# My user can't upload files to folders owned by www-data

Tags: permissions, webserver

I think I have screwed up my permissions in Ubuntu.

I am using my server to run PHP. I recently ran across a problem where PHP could not create directories in the `var/www`-directory, so I searched around on the internet. Now PHP can write and access anything like it should, but as a user, I can't create new folders or files anymore.

Right now, the permissions for folders are like this:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 www-data www-data [Folders]
```

This is the permissions when I upload using sftp:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gautvedt www-data [Folders]
```

What have I done wrong and how can I change this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include yourself into the www-data `group`.

[Graphical method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto)

Command line:

```
sudo adduser gautvedt www-data
```

That way you can add things to directories where `www-data` owns the group.

---

There are more methods but this is the easiest one.

Answer (score 5):

After add user to `www-data` group as mentioned by [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind),  you should change the permission to 755

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www
```

without changing permission, it can't be accessed (forbidden).  So, it will change to

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 gautvedt www-data [Folders]
```

Comment: To me anything that does not need executing should be set to `644` and not `0755` ;)

Comment: For me it was enough to have `read` right and own the file to upload.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (at least) you can use...

gpasswd -a **username** www-data

this will add the www-data group to the existing user account